# Cannot create more than 2 txt.files in Python

Tags: python

Trying to clean up a txt file from a USB GPS and having trouble with 3rd `for loop`. Currently have...

```
deletes = ['$GPGGA', '$GPGSA', '$GPGSV', '$PSRF156', ]
searchquery = '$GPRMC'

with open('Drive_home.txt_rf') as f1:
    with open('Drive_home_1.txt', 'w+') as f2:
        for lines in f1:
            if not any(delete in lines for delete in deletes):
                f2.write(lines)

with open('Drive_home_1.txt') as f2:
    with open('Drive_home_2.txt', 'w+') as f3:
            lines = f2.readlines()
            for i, line in enumerate(lines2):
                if line.startswith(searchquery):
                    f3.write(line)
                    f3.write(lines[i + 1])

with open('Drive_home_2.txt') as f3:
    with open('Drive_home_3.txt', 'w+') as f4:
        for lines in f3:
            if len(lines.rstrip('\n')) >= 105:
                f4.write(lines)
```

For some reason, the script is not creating the 'Drive_home_3.txt.' so not sure why its not.

Also, is it possible just to create one .txt with all `for loop`?

Update: Currently, Drive_home_1.txt and Drive_home_2.txt will be created to the desktop but Drive_home_3.txt is not. I have tried a quick search of that file but nothing comes up so I was assuming it was just not being created.

This is the exact code that I'm using. I just noticed that `lines2` should just be `lines`. I also get the error...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users****\Desktop\TestV6.py", line 16, in 
    f3.write(lines[i + 1])
IndexError: list index out of range

I assume that error is just from the data collection at the end of my file which looks like...

```
$GPRMC  211536  A   3512.0329   N   8507.6987   W   0.24    220.94  300818  A*70                                    
    96.5    50  2   3   -3  236 0   1   1   30-08-18    17:15:36:551                                
$GPRMC  211537  A   3512.0329   N   8507.6987   W   0   220.94  300818  A*77                                    
    96.5    49  2   3   -4  236 0   1   1   30-08-18    17:15:37:549                                
$GPRMC  211538  A   3512.0325   N   8507.6985   W   0.31    220.94  300818  A*74                                    
    96.5    49  2   3   -2  236 0   1   1   30-08-18    17:15:38:469                                
$GPRMC  211539  A   3512.0325   N   8507.6985   W   0   220.94  300818  A*77                                    
$GPRMC  211540  A   3512.0324   N   8507.6986   W   0.07    220.94  300818  A*7C                                    
$GPRMC  211540  A   3512.0324   N   8507.6986   W   0.07    220.94  300818  A*7C                                    
$GPRMC  211541  A   3512.0324   N   8507.6986   W   0   220.94  300818  A*7A                                    
$GPRMC  211541  A   3512.0324   N   8507.6986   W   0   220.94  300818  A*7A
```

Update 2:

Cleaned up the script and now I have...

```
deletes = ['$GPGGA', '$GPGSA', '$GPGSV', '$PSRF156', ]
searchquery = '$GPRMC'

with open('Drive_home.txt_rf') as f1:
    with open('Drive_home_1.txt', 'w+') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith(searchquery):
                if not any(delete in lines[i + 1] for delete in deletes):
                    f2.write(line)
                    f2.write(lines[i + 1])
```

Which outputs one txt. and looks like...

```
$GPRMC  204249  A   3504.5449   N   8509.0603   W   0.31    352.89  300818  A*7F                                    
    96.5    39  5   14  -2  200 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:46:365                                
$GPRMC  204250  A   3504.5449   N   8509.0605   W   0.32    352.89  300818  A*72                                    
    96.5    39  7   22  -3  168 0   0   0   30-08-18    16:42:47:364                                
$GPRMC  204251  A   3504.5448   N   8509.0606   W   0.77    352.89  300818  A*70                                    
    96.5    32  9   24  -2  184 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:48:362                                
$GPRMC  204252  A   3504.5448   N   8509.0608   W   0.37    352.89  300818  A*79                                    
    96.5    43  9   15  -4  236 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:49:454                                
$GPRMC  204253  A   3504.545    N   8509.0609   W   0.14    352.89  300818  A*71                                    
    96.5    37  23  17  -4  184 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:50:967                                
$GPRMC  204254  A   3504.545    N   8509.061    W   1.52    50.91   300818  A*45                                    
    96.5    38  10  21  -3  184 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:51:451
```

Now I have a question again, is there away to join the line after "$GPRMC with next line to look like below?

```
$GPRMC  204244  A   3504.5446   N   8509.0599   W   0   352.89  300818  A*7F 96.5   40  6   11  1   236 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:41:451                                                                        
$GPRMC  204245  A   3504.5447   N   8509.0598   W   0.27    352.89  300818  A*7B 96.5   44  6   9   -9  236 0   1   1   30-08-18    16:42:42:434                                
$GPRMC  204246  A   3504.5447   N   8509.0598   W   0   352.89  300818  A*7D 96.5   44  7   14  1   217 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:43:401                                
$GPRMC  204247  A   3504.5448   N   8509.0599   W   0.25    352.89  300818  A*75 96.5   35  14  21  2   151 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:44:400
```

I'm not sure how `.join()` works or if there is a way to concatenate every other line or with previous line `if line.startwith`. I'm not sure if that every other line will be an issue joining since it has integers and floats in it.

Comment: any error messages? beause it _should_ create the file, even empty

Comment: Is this your actual exact code? Where is `lines2` defined?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't create `Drive_home_3.txt`? Update the question with what you know. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `f3.write(lines[i + 1])` will give you the exception as `i+1` may be equal to `len(lines)` and since the array is 0-indexed that'd be an out of range access. You should make sure that that's not the case before you try to access `lines[i + 1]`. (e.g. `(i+1)<length(lines)`)

Comment: When your program is generating an exception, always include it in the question. And in general, it's best to include the full Traceback as the last error line is not always the most important line.

Answer (score 0):

It is not creating the file because the script is stopping with an error before it reaches the point in the code where it would create it. The error you are getting tells you this because it is point to the line `f3.write(lines[i+1])` which is the one immediately before the block of code that creates the third file.

The error you are getting (`list index out of range`) tells you that this error is occurring because you are trying to access an element of `lines` that does not exist. This is happening because you are looping over the final element of `lines` and then trying to access the element after it (The `i+1`th element).